# How to prevent clang/llvm compile local variables to global?

Tags: c, gcc, clang, llvm

I have a C code:

```
int64_t sample_max(int64_t *beg, int64_t len) {
    if (len == 0) {
        return 0;
    }
    int64_t max = 0x8000000000000000;
    int64_t *end = beg + len;
    while (beg < end) {
        if (*beg > max) {
            max = *beg;
        }
        beg++;
    }
    return max;
}
```

and complie it by clang:

```
clang -S -target x86_64-unknown-none -masm=intel -mno-red-zone -mstackrealign -mllvm -inline-threshold=1000 -fno-asynchronous-unwind-tables -fno-exceptions -fno-rtti -O3 -fno-builtin -ffast-math -mavx2 lib/sample.c -o lib/sample_avx2.s
```

and I found the clang/llvm complie the local variables "max = 0x8000000000000000" to global :

```
vpbroadcastq    ymm0, qword ptr [rip + .LCPI1_0]
    vmovdqa ymm3, ymm0
    vmovdqa ymm2, ymm0
    vmovdqa ymm1, ymm0

....

.LCPI1_0:
    .quad   -9223372036854775808    # 0x8000000000000000
    .section    .rodata,"a",@progbits
    .align  32
```

How to prevent clang/llvm compile local variables to global?
Could we compile 0x8000000000000000 to a immediate values?

Thanks.

Comment: Why do you want that? And what asm do you expect exactly? Some movabsq followed by a move to an XMM register (possibly through memory depending on the exact target) and finally the broadcast?

Comment: The local variables are not global. The compiler is using registers for them. It is storing 0x8000000000000000 with effectively static storage duration. 0x8000000000000000 is a constant, not a variable. The compiler is free to implement it as it desires. What is your concern about how it is stored—why do you care, what effect does it have for you?

Comment: @MarcGlisse @Eric Postpischil I want convert these asm to the go-asm by `c2goasm`. And I meet a issue https://github.com/minio/c2goasm/issues/8

Comment: @EricPostpischil  I want convert these asm to the go-asm by c2goasm. And I meet a issue github.com/minio/c2goasm/issues/8

Comment: Compile using -Os flag. This will stop the generation of global jump tables. Tested with clang 3.8